# Char parameter repeates n times in Java code

Tags: java

Need to write method complete that takes two parameters –a character and an integer. The method should return a String which contains the character parameter repeated n times, where n is the value of the integer parameter .For example: fill('z',3) should return "zzz".
fill('b',7)should return"bbbbbbb".
I am not allowed to use collection, as I am new in Java..
I am trying to write a code:

```
public class first{
String fill(char s, int times) {
if (times <= 0) return "";
else return s + repeat(s, times-1);
}
```

How can be char used here?

Comment: `return "" + s + repeat(s, times-1);`

Comment: To elaborate, Murilo's code works since Java casts everything to the type that's left of the +. In your code it sees s + <String>, and s is a char so it casts the result of the recursive call to char, and fails at that. In Murilo's code, it casts s to a String first, then adds the string from the recursive call to it.

Answer (score 1):

Without recursion and very simple:

```
public class StringFill {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(fill('x', 5));
    }

    public static String fill (char c, int howMany) {
        if (howMany < 1) return "";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i=0; i<howMany; i++) sb.append(c);
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

As an alternative choice you could go for the ready-to-use [Apache Commons Lang StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) method [repeat](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#repeat%28char,%20int%29).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a homework problem: So I am not going to show any code but you have many different options.

1. Recursion
2. Use `StringBuilder` and use a loop.
3. Create a `byte[]` and loop through it and use `new String(myBytes, Charset.fromName('ASCII'));`

Comment: Also, if you care about efficiency, #3 is probably the most efficient, although #2 might be. You would just have to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace repeat by fill. Also add a return in case times is 1.

```
Public class first {
  String fill(char s, int times) {
    if (times <= 0) return "";
    else if (times == 1) return s;
    else return s += fill(s, times-1);
  }
}
```

Also, it's good practice to declare your function private, protected or public and not to leave it on default.

Comment: in this string "else if (times == 1) return s;" program says "incompatible types" about "s"...

Comment: You can replace it by 'String.valueOf(s);' or by 's + ""' (s + an empty String, which will automatically get converted to a String). Sorry, I couldn't test last time :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey how about something like this:

```
public class Example
{
    public void charsTimesN(char c, int n)
    {
      int i = 1;
      if (n < 0)
      {
         System.out.println("Error");
      } 
      else 
      {
         while (i <= n)
         {
            System.out.print(c);
            i++;
         }
      }
    }
}
```

Then have a main class method:

```
public class UseExample
{
   public static void main(String args [])
   {
      char c = 'f';
      int n = 10;
      Example e = new Example();
      e.charsTimesN(c, n);
   }
}
```

Outputs: 
ffffffffff

Hope that helps!